# An issue regarding spacing using fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(); how can I add enough spacing so titles of each fig do not overlap?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I am having trouble with spacing for my visualization below. I intend to make just a simple text visualization that displays the counts of movies and tv shows. The problem I have is regarding the titles. When I assign each fig to a row/column, it is centering on the number being displayed, which makes the titles for each fig overlap. I tried adding more rows to space it out, but that caused more trouble than good. Is there a way to add more padding between each fig? I tried a few different things, but I am relatively unfamiliar to plotly and how everything comes together sometimes. Perhaps there is another way of doing this visualization and I am overcomplicating it. There is a link to my output below too.

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    value = 12354,
    number={'font':{'color': '#00A8E1','size':85}},
    title = {"text": "Movies<br><span style='font-size:0.8em;color:gray'>On Prime Video</span>"},
    domain = {'row': 0,'column': 0}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    value = 2144,
    number={'font':{'color': '#00A8E1','size':85}},
    title = {"text": "TV Shows<br><span style='font-size:0.8em;color:gray'>On Prime Video</span>"},
    domain = {'row': 0,'column': 1}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    value = 3560,
    number={'font':{'color': '#E50914','size':70}},
    title = {"text": "Movies<br><span style='font-size:0.8em;color:gray'>On Netflix</span>"},
    domain = {'row': 1, 'column': 0}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    value = 1931,
    number={'font':{'color': '#E50914','size':70}},
    title = {"text": "TV Shows<br><span style='font-size:0.8em;color:gray'>On Netflix</span>"},
    domain = {'row': 1, 'column': 1}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    value = 903,
    number={'font':{'color': '#66AA33','size':60}},
    title = {"text": "Movies<br><span style='font-size:0.8em;color:gray'>On Hulu</span>"},
    domain = {'row': 2, 'column': 0}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    value = 1754,
    number={'font':{'color': '#66AA33','size':60}},
    title = {"text": "TV Shows<br><span style='font-size:0.8em;color:gray'>On Hulu</span>"},
    domain = {'row': 2, 'column': 1}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    value = 564,
    number={'font':{'color': '#113CCF','size':50}},
    title = {"text": "Movies<br><span style='font-size:0.8em;color:gray'>On Disney+</span>"},
    domain = {'row': 3, 'column': 0}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number",
    value = 180,
    number={'font':{'color': '#113CCF','size':50}},
    title = {"text": "TV Shows<br><span style='font-size:0.8em;color:gray'>On Disney+</span>"},
    domain = {'row': 3, 'column': 1}))


fig.update_layout(
    grid = {'rows': 4, 'columns': 2})
```

#### Result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFfjT.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
fig.update_layout(height = 800)
```

This isn't *very* dynamic, but replacing `800` with something that is termined by the number and size of the elements in your visualization is the way to go if it's too cumbersome to set it manually.

#### Result:

[image]